# Involve Record Key in Kafka Connect Sink Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, transformation, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

By using single message transformations(SMTs) e.g InsertField Transformation, it is possible to embed meta data such as partition, offset, topic name, timestamp etc. But, not the record key. In our use-case, we would like to embed it just like other meta-data fields as a separate field. Is there any possibility to achieve this objective?

By now, I have checked the [Confluent documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/insertfield.html#properties). But, unfortunately only other meta data fields are provided.

Comment: Seen this? https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-transform-archive